# PyQt | Signals not handled in QThread but in main thread

Tags: pyqt, qthread

In this simple PyQt demo program, I emit signals from the main thread. In a worker thread I connect to them, but the signal handlers are run in the main thread:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import threading
from time import sleep
import sys


class Data():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "Data having %d and %d" % (self.a, self.b)

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.p = parent

    def run(self):
        self.connect(self.p, QtCore.SIGNAL("newTask"), self.task)
        print "[%s] running exec_()" % threading.currentThread()
        self.exec_()

    def task(self, dataobj):
        print "[%s] Processing" % threading.currentThread(), dataobj
        sleep(3)
        print "Done with", dataobj
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("taskDone"), str(dataobj))

class App(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.w = Worker(self)
        self.connect(self.w, QtCore.SIGNAL("taskDone"), self.on_task_done)
        self.w.start()

    def assign_tasks(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("newTask"), Data(3, 4))
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("newTask"), Data(5, 6))
        print "[%s] Tasks sent" % threading.currentThread()

    @staticmethod
    def on_task_done(objstr):
        print "[%s] App: Worker finished with" % threading.currentThread(), objstr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = App()
    sleep(1)
    a.assign_tasks()
    sleep(20)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But the result reveals that the callbacks are run in the main thread:

```
[<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 105564)>] running exec_()
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 105612)>] Processing Data having 3 and 4
Done with Data having 3 and 4
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 105612)>] App: Worker finished with Data having 3 and 4
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 105612)>] Processing Data having 5 and 6
Done with Data having 5 and 6
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 105612)>] App: Worker finished with Data having 5 and 6
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 105612)>] Tasks sent
```

What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, the PyQt docs on this are very incomplete and contradicting.

I'm getting similar results if I use the `moveToThread` technique:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import threading
from time import sleep
import sys

class Data():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "Data having %d and %d" % (self.a, self.b)

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.connect(parent, QtCore.SIGNAL("newTask"), self.task)

    def task(self, dataobj):
        print "[%s] Processing" % threading.currentThread(), dataobj
        sleep(3)
        print "Done with", dataobj
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("taskDone"), str(dataobj))

    def start(self):
        print "[%s] start()" % threading.currentThread()

class App(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

        self.w = Worker(self)
        self.t = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.w.moveToThread(self.t)
        self.connect(self.w, QtCore.SIGNAL("taskDone"), self.on_task_done)
        self.connect(self.t, QtCore.SIGNAL("started()"), self.w.start)
        self.t.start()

    def assign_tasks(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("newTask"), Data(3, 4))
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("newTask"), Data(5, 6))
        print "[%s] Tasks sent" % threading.currentThread()

    @staticmethod
    def on_task_done(objstr):
        print "[%s] App: Worker finished with" % threading.currentThread(), objstr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = App()
    sleep(1)
    a.assign_tasks()
    sleep(20)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which results in:

```
[<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 108992)>] start()
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 107004)>] Processing Data having 3 and 4
Done with Data having 3 and 4
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 107004)>] App: Worker finished with Data having 3 and 4
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 107004)>] Processing Data having 5 and 6
Done with Data having 5 and 6
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 107004)>] App: Worker finished with Data having 5 and 6
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 107004)>] Tasks sent
```

Comment: I managed to get the second pattern to work, the one that uses `moveToThread`, by `connect()`ing the signals in `Worker.start()` instead of `Worker.init()`. `start()` is the first thing that runs in the worker thread. I still wonder why it doesn't work with the first pattern... I know the "new" way is different, but what is going on??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `Worker` objects 'live' in the main thread, that means all their signals will be handled by the main thread's event loop. The fact that these objects are `QThread`s doesn't change that.

If you want signals to be processed by a different thread, you first need to move the worker object to that thread by using it's [`moveToThread`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#moveToThread) method.

So in your case, only the `run` method is acutally executed in a different thread, the `task` method is still executed in the main thread. A way of changing this would be:

- make your `Worker` a regular `QObject`, not a `QThread`
- create a `QThread` in your `App`, start it and move the worker to that thread
- then send the signal to the worker that causes it to start processing

And you should check out these references:

- [QObject thread affinity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity)
- [Qt threading basics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/thread-basics.html)
- [Multithreading technologies in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-technologies.html)

---

edit:

A few other things I noticed in your code:

- you're mixing python threading and qt threading. `threading.currentThread` will *not* correctly reflect the current qt thread. use `QThread.currentThread()` for that.
- decorate the slots you're calling as `pyqtSlots`, not doing so can be a cause of problems like these.
- use [new style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). Old style signals are no longer supported in PyQt5, and new style signals are much easier and nicer to use.

So here is a version of your code that should work:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import threading
from time import sleep
import sys

class Data():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "Data having %d and %d" % (self.a, self.b)

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    taskDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        parent.newTask.connect(self.task)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def task(self, dataobj):
        print "[%s] Processing" % QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName(), dataobj
        sleep(3)
        print "Done with", dataobj
        self.taskDone.emit(str(dataobj))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        print "[%s] start()" % QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()

class App(QtCore.QObject):

    newTask = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.w = Worker(self)
        self.t = QtCore.QThread(self, objectName='workerThread')
        self.w.moveToThread(self.t)
        self.w.taskDone.connect(self.on_task_done)
        self.t.started.connect(self.w.start)
        self.t.start()

    def assign_tasks(self):
        self.newTask.emit(Data(3, 4))
        self.newTask.emit(Data(5, 6))
        print "[%s] Tasks sent" % QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()

    @staticmethod
    def on_task_done(objstr):
        print "[%s] App: Worker finished with" % QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName(), objstr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtCore.QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')
    a = App()
    sleep(1)
    a.assign_tasks()
    from utils import sigint
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've set the thread's `objectName`s to make the output better readable:

```
[workerThread] start()
[main] Tasks sent
[workerThread] Processing Data having 3 and 4
Done with Data having 3 and 4
[workerThread] Processing Data having 5 and 6
[main] App: Worker finished with Data having 3 and 4
Done with Data having 5 and 6
[main] App: Worker finished with Data having 5 and 6
```

Comment: I tried the `moveToThread` pattern, but the results are similar. In the example shown, only `run()` seems to run in the worker thread, but with the `moveToThread` pattern, only what I connect to the thread object's `started()` signal runs in the separate thread. I cannot get the object to respond to signals sent from the application. Maybe I have to start some kind of event listener in `run()`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This looks like the correct way of doing this. I'm migrating my app from Gtk+3 to PyQt4 for stability, but the thread usage pattern, with separate thread and worker objects, puzzles me. I seems like I'm using twice as much code for the same thing. How does this `moveToThread`-thing and connecting signals between thread and worker and main help? Thanks again!